# flutter Lottie animation issue

Tags: android, flutter, animation, lottie

I am using Lottie animation in my flutter app . I got a error saying that "Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $

Comment: add your code and lottie json

Comment: What I can understand from this little info is that your lottie animation json file is not correct (malformed).

Comment: Which package are you using currently in order to render your lottie animations?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/lottie

Comment: Hey was this issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I updated the version of lottie, and I also found it better to download lottie in json format.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  lottie: ^2.4.0
```

and in assets like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/lottie/
```

the code call lottie:

```
Positioned(
  top: size.height * 0.05,
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    child: SimpleShadow(
      child: Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/lottie-file.json'),
    )),
),
```

***OBS: SimpleShadow() is a library***

```
dependencies:
  simple_shadow: ^0.3.1
```

Result:

[image]

Inside the line are lotties

**I hope it helps**